# How to remove previously overwritten Ubuntu OS from showing up in Boot Option Menu?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, boot-loader, bios

I got a new laptop and installed Ubuntu OS. I decided to change my mind and installed Debian instead, and overwrote my hard drive completely deleting anything that was on it before. I successfully installed the new OS, but now everytime my computer boots, it takes me straight to something called a grub menu even after changing the boot order in bios, so I have to go into the boot menu, and boot my new OS manually every time. In this boot menu, it still shows my old ubuntu for some reason, which takes me to that grub menu if I select it. How do I remove this ubuntu remnant so I can delete every trace of it and just boot straight into my new OS?

```
Boot options:
OS boot Manager (UEFI) - ubuntu (DF4032) // how to remove this completly
OS boot Manager (UEFI) - debian (DF4032)
Boot From EFI File
```

Comment: I booted my computer and when it went into the grub menu, I typed update-grub and nothing happened. I just want to get rid of this thing and the ubuntu trace so I can just boot straight into Debian without this bash thing appearing.

Comment: I opened a terminal and typed update-grub, then it said, 1) generatingn grub configuration file, 2) found background image: .background_cache.png, 3) found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz/debian... 4) found initrd image /boot/initrd/debian... 5) adding boot menu entry for efi firmware configuration 6) done, then i rebooted my computer and it still took me into the grub bash menu.